# Is there a way to manage KDB keystore from python?

Tags: python-3.x, keystore, ibmhttpserver

I'm looking for any libraries like "jks" which is used to manage jks keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Not in any meaningful way that I am aware of, but most software that uses CMS *.kdb files can use PKCS12 files nowadays which are not proprietary.

The PKCS12 files just have to meet a few simple criteria to be used with IBM GSKit-based SW:

- The file must have a password
- The private keys inside can be unencrypted or encrypted with the same password, but not a different password.
- Certificates accompanied by private keys should have pkcs12 "friendly names" to use as labels.